# GDB Debugging on Eclipse hangs for infinite time

Tags: eclipse, gdb, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I downloaded Eclipse for C++ v 3.6 32-bit version on my Windows 7 64-bit OS.

I can build and run my code, but I cannot debug.

I am using MingW32 compiler v5.1.6 with GDB v7.1 .

When try to "debug" my application, the progress tab shows "Launching: Configuring GDB" at 86% for infinite time. The stop button beside the progress bar does not work where says "Cancel Requested". Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem fixed. `MinGW\bin` folder did not have the file `libexpat-1.dll` for some reason. Downloaded the file from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/expat/expat-2.0.1-1/libexpat-2.0.1-1-mingw32-dll-1.tar.gz/download) and extracted to `MinGW\bin` and everything working smoothly :)

Comment: On MinGW downloads under `Extension` / `expat`.